# Can we have granular approval/rejection?

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-examples

It's probably not that simple to implement but it would greatly help us out emptying the current backlog of changes.

### user story

- user A submits 2 examples X and Y on the same topic

  - user B knows about X *but not* about Y
  - user C knows about Y *but not* about X
- user B (partially) rejects X

  - Y remains in the queue and X too until someone else rejects/approves it as well
- user C (partially) approves Y

  - Y is green on the proposed changed page (that part can't be rejected anymore)
  - user A is notified of the partial approval
- user D (partially) rejects X

  - the proposed change quits the queue
  - user A is notified of the partial rejection

Comment: In general a nice idea, in theory. In practice I wonder how this can be implemented with a nice user experience...

Comment: This will only serve to over-complicate the review process.
I'd rather see examples as separate entities altogether. With a review for each example. So, an edit to an example will not place the whole _topic_ in the review queue.