# Allow us to roll back a Documentation example, not just an entire topic

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

So today I was fielding a flag about another run of plagiarism on Documentation, and found an edit on an example that was plagiarized from a Programmers answer. The rest of the example was original, just this edit was plagiarized.

I wanted to roll back the edit, so I went to the revision history for the example, picked the revision right before the plagiarism, chose View Topic and chose the option "Create draft rolling back to this version" (as [described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329396/how-to-mark-a-docs-change-as-invalid-and-revert-it/329451#329451)).

Only oops, there had been a bunch of revisions since them on other examples in this topic, revisions that were not listed under the example I was looking at. So I accidentally had blown away all those changes and had to go dig through the topic's revision history to find the correct revision on the *entire topic* that took me to a point before the plagiarism was inserted.

Could we have a way of rolling back edits just within the scope of a specific example, ignoring the rest of the topic? Also, the rollback options should be present directly in the revision history, because I didn't even know how to do this until shown by an SE employee.

Comment: or more alternatively, _View edit_ could also offer a rollback option (instead of just _view topic_). In general I like your feature request. It could also be part of generally being able to split up edits and approve the one half and reject the other half…

Comment: Bravo! Adding this granularity would help greatly when reviewing Examples.

Comment: @bwoebi http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329577/can-we-have-granular-approval-rejection

Comment: @Knu yes, I'm aware, I even commented there. The main point is giving the reviewer the ability to separate something into concrete drafts which are rejected/approved individually instead of being able to reject/approve in the **same** draft (which I think will be quite confusing).

Comment: @markE http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328614/approve-or-reject-specific-examples-only

Comment: I had a similar problem which let to the problems mentioned in this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330313/cant-discard-retracted-draft

Comment: What really makes this feature a bite in the behind is that you can't even see *what you're removing*. It does create a draft for you to review, but there's no diff to see what's changing between the current version of the topic and the draft you're creating. It's already done everything for you and just has some labels next to each example describing what's changed with no way to see what the system changed or, more importantly, if those changes are what you intend.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you view the revision history for an *example*, view the previous version of a topic will display an option to rollback just that example.

[image]

Comment: @TravisJ should be fixed, some new calculations for "who has contributed to this" made some incorrect assumptions about timing.

Comment: This feature is close to impossible to find. Restoring a deleted example: view topic - view history - find edit - view topic - find example - view history - find edit - view topic - find example - rollback - publish.

Answer (score 59):

Here's an idea. I know it's crazy, but hear me out.

Let's have examples be the primary unit of documentation, with each example separate from all others.

Now I know [nobody's ever heard this one before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328559/documentation-split-edits-by-example-rather-than-topic?rq=1). This wasn't a topic of heated debate during the closed beta. And we've [never had a site work where individual posts are actually individual posts](https://stackoverflow.com/), rather than having combined editing.

But it might just work.

</sarcasm>

Comment: Many contributions to docs will involve splitting and merging examples, which might not figure into your plan. (Well, it doesn't jibe with the current system either.) Also, separately edited posts would require more reviews and (probably) more work for editors, even if they are just sweeping through to fix some out-of-date thing.

Comment: Given the some examples should be in more then one topic as they cover how to use two systems together.....

Comment: Fine, if we do that. You should though still be able to submit an edit which touches multiple examples at once. But this should not be too much of a problem I guess…

Comment: We definitively need this feature. This will make reviewing easier and not harder. Often editors mix unnecessary or wrong edits to multiple examples along with correct (or completely new example) that is worth approving while other changes are not.

Comment: The "heated debate during the closed beta"...what was the counter-argument? Everything becomes easier when we mash it into opaque blobs? Merging was so much better back when everyone used CVS?