# Rollback Single Example is Not Working

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, rollbacks, documentation-drafts

I [previously posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330313/cant-discard-retracted-draft) about an example that was changed and deleted and how I couldn't rollback just that one example. A single example rollback feature was [implemented yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/331934/4660897), so I decided to go back and try again to rollback the one example.

I went to the example revision history, found the topic version I wanted to rollback to, and clicked on the "Create rollback draft" button. The image below shows how I wanted the code to look:

> [image]

**Problem #1:** When the new draft was created however, the example contained the latest version of code, not the one I rolled back to:

> [image]

I then replaced the code in the editor with the older code that I wanted and then submitted the draft for approval.

**Problem #2:** I went to view my proposed change, and as you can see in the picture below, the code was again reverted to the latest version of code, ignoring what I had written in the editor:

> [image]

I'm not sure if this has anything to do with the fact that I am trying to undo a delete as part of my rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed with the latest deploy.

There was a bug where it was assumed that a draft which undeleted an example *only* undeleted the example.  This made rolling back in the case where an example had been both edited and deleted behave incorrectly.

Comment: Just tried it again. Problem #1 was fixed, yet not Problem #2. As soon as I submit my change, it goes back to the original latest version of the code, and ignores what was in the editor.

Comment: @TotZam hmm, strange - digging.

Comment: @TotZam found it: bug in display for non-moderator/non-tag-badge-holders - should be fixed.

Comment: Yup, worked now.